# Are there extension points in the Clang static libraries that I can leverage to add metadata to functions?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm working on a project that parses C headers with the Clang static libraries (not libclang) for binary program analysis purposes. I consume the AST and do not rely on codegen.

I would love to be able to add some additional metadata to functions by modifying the header files that they appear in. Specifically, I'd like to add the expected address of the function in the binary program. This could be one way to do it:

```
int foo(int bar) __attribute__((address(0xdeadbeef)));
```

Attributes are especially convenient because they are easy to embed in a macro, which could end up looking like:

```
#define ADDRESS(x) __attribute__((address(x)))
int foo(int bar) ADDRESS(0xdeadbeef);
```

Since this is an open-source project maintained by me only, I would prefer to not fork Clang, and just allow people to build my program with their distributions' stock Clang packages. Sadly, this apparently means that I can't use attributes for this purpose, because the attribute list appears to be hard-coded into Clang, and there doesn't seem to be any attribute that I can co-opt for this purpose.

Are there extension points that I can leverage in the Clang static libraries to allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per Eli Friedman](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2016-October/051371.html), the `annotate` attribute can be used for this purpose. An example usage would be:

```
int foo(int bar) __attribute__((annotate("address:0xdeadbeef")));
```